# Getting error Error Code -1: java.io.IOException: Unknown unpack type: 196

Tags: aerospike

I am trying to fetch data from aerospike using scanCallback() method. After running for some time without scanning the aerospike completely I am getting the error

```
    "Error Code -1: java.io.IOException: Unknown unpack type: 196"
```

I don't have any idea of what this error means and there is no online documentation for this error online too. I am struggling with this error for sometime now:( Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means one of bins in the record is a list or map and one of the list/map elements can't be parsed.  A temporary workaround is to set includeBinData to false, scan keys and use key to read each record individually.

```
public void runScan()
{
    ScanPolicy policy = new ScanPolicy();
    policy.concurrentNodes = false;
    policy.includeBinData = false;

    client.scanAll(policy, namespace, set, this);
}

@Override
public void scanCallback(Key key, Record record) {
    try {
        Record rec = client.get(null, key);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // Now we know the key with the corrupt record.
        System.out.println("Error reading " + key);
    }
}
```

Once the key has been identified, try reading specific bins to see which bin in the record is causing the problem.  That bin may have to be re-written.